# Calculating delta in SpriteKit using Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am attempting to learn swift by refactoring one of my old games and I need to rewrite my `update` method which calculates a delta time. This code *works* but is ugly. How would I go about *properly* rewriting this?

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var lastUpdateTimeInterval: CFTimeInterval?

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

        var delta: CFTimeInterval?
        if let luti = lastUpdateTimeInterval {
            delta = currentTime - luti
        } else {
            delta = currentTime
        }

        lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime;

        if (delta > 1.0) {
            delta = minTimeInterval;
            lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime;
        }

        updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate(delta!)
    }
}
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for working code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question belongs to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). But I just post answer here and hope it will be migrate to the correct place along with the question.

You have some redundant code, this is my first iteration re-write

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var lastUpdateTimeInterval: CFTimeInterval?

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

        var delta: CFTimeInterval = currentTime // no reason to make it optional
        if let luti = lastUpdateTimeInterval {
            delta = currentTime - luti
        }

        lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime

        if delta > 1.0 {
            delta = minTimeInterval
            // this line is redundant lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime
        }

        updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate(delta)
    }
}
```

and further simplified

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var lastUpdateTimeInterval: CFTimeInterval = 0

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

        var delta: CFTimeInterval = currentTime - lastUpdateTimeInterval

        lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime

        if delta > 1.0 {
            delta = minTimeInterval
        }

        updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate(delta)
    }
}
```

You can replace the `if` with `?:`, but some people just hate it for some reason

```
updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate(delta > 1.0 ? minTimeInterval : delta)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if delta >= 1.0` if he wants to make sure exactly a second has passed?