# Can you apply delta time to an SKAction

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I've started to notice in the game that I'm making that as the fps goes down as more nodes are on the screen, the nodes start to move with a little choppiness to them. I move the nodes with:

```
    let ran = Int(arc4random_uniform(1400));
    let monster = SKSpriteNode(texture: text)
    monster.position = CGPoint(x: ran, y: 800);

    let move = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(monster.position.x, -100), duration: 2);
    let remove = SKAction.runBlock { () -> Void in
        score += 1;
        monster.removeFromParent()
    }
    monster.runAction(SKAction.sequence([move,remove]));
```

Can i use delta time to effect the nodes movements? How do i do this? Would it make any difference?

Comment: How many nodes do yo have on screen ? What is your draw count ? You can enable these in view controller (showsNodeCount = true, showsDrawCount = true).

Comment: @Whirlwind about 80 - 90 nodes, 4 draws,fps down to 50

Comment: That seems fine ... Do you test on device or simulator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do much about your FPS slowing down as you add more nodes to your view. Which device is running your app also determines your FPS. Newer models have a much faster CPU.

To use delta time you can do something like this:

```
-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval) currentTime {
    NSTimeInterval delta = currentTime - self.lastUpdateTime;
    self.lastUpdateTime = currentTime;
    // use the delta time to determine how much your sprites need to move to stay in sync.
}
```

If you are looking for a Swift version of the code, look at this previous Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728881/calculating-delta-in-spritekit-using-swift).

You cannot slow down or speed up an SKAction in mid run. To adjust speed of movement you will have to move your node manually by either applying a physics force such as CGVectorMake or by changing its x,y positions.

---

Add this property:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval lastUpdateTime;
```

Then in your `update` method:

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

NSTimeInterval delta = currentTime - self.lastUpdateTime;
self.lastUpdateTime = currentTime;

// sanity check
if(delta > 1)
    delta = 0;

float distanceToMovePerSecond = 5.0f;
float numberOfFramesPerSecond = 60.0f;

float xPosition = ((distanceToMovePerSecond/numberOfFramesPerSecond) * delta) * 100;

myNode0.position = CGPointMake(myNode0.position.x+xPosition, myNode0.position.y);
```

}

Comment: When changing the position in the update method with -  myNode.position = CGPoint(x: myNode.position.x, y: myNode.position.y - (speed * deltaTime),  its telling me that (speed * deltaTime) isn't a cgpoint, but how else would i change the y position

Comment: @user3593148  It's more of a speed*time = distance matter. If, for example, you want your node to move 100 to the right in 1 second time. You can use the delta time to make sure this happens within the 1 second.

Comment: yea i know that, what im asking is how, if i do CGPoint(x: myNode.position.x, y: myNode.position.y - 5, this works, the node will move down 5 points per frame, but how would i write that with delta time in it

Comment: @user3593148 - updated. Sorry but my Swift is not that good so I had to do it in Obj-C.